# Container that returns random value based on a chance/wight

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, containers

How would I best go about making a Container class that returns random values based on a weight that was entered during adding of an element?

Ideally it should be usable like this:

```
var randomContainer = new RandomContainer<IThing>();
randomContainer.Add(new CoolThing(), 80);
randomContainer.Add(new AwesomeThing(), 20);
IThing thing = randomContainer.Get();
```

So thing would have an 80% chance of being CoolThing and a 20% chance of being an AwesomeThing.

But the algorithm shouldn't require the weights to add up to 100, so this should be possible too:

```
var randomContainer = new RandomContainer<IThing>();
randomContainer.Add(new CoolThing(), 398);
randomContainer.Add(new AwesomeThing(), 485);
randomContainer.Add(new SpecialThing(), 1);
IThing thing = randomContainer.Get();
```

Any ideas how to implement such an algorithm? What members/properties should the class have? Does it make sense to implement ICollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That algorithm should be pretty simple:

select a random value between 1 and the sum of all weights. The value will indicate which object to return.

Example for your second sample:

- Values 1 to 398 would return `CoolThing`.
- Values 399 to 883 (= 398 + 485) would return `AwesomeThing`
- Value 884 would return `SpecialThing`

Answer (score 1):

I'm marking Daniel Hilgarth's answer as right, since he got me on the right track.

For anyone wanting an example implementation:

```
public class RandomContainer<T> 
{
    private Random _random = new Random();

    private Dictionary<T, int> _objects = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    private int _weightSum;

    public RandomContainer()
    {           
    }

    public void Add(T obj, int weight)
    {          
        _objects.Add(obj, weight);
        _weightSum += weight;
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        int sumExtra = 0;
        int rand = _random.Next(0, _weightSum);
        foreach(var kvp in _objects)
        {
            if(rand < kvp.Value + sumExtra)
                return kvp.Key;
            sumExtra += kvp.Value;
        }
        return default(T); // This shouldn't be reached
    }
}
```

It doesn't contain many standard methods, but the meat lies in the Get() function anyway, and the rest should be easy enough to implement.

Comment: Is it to be expected that this container will hold a huge amount of items? Because your current implementation is O(n).

Comment: Please note that `Random.Next` has an *exclusive* upper bound. It has to be `_random.Next(1, _weightSum + 1)`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks for the hints, fixed the upper bound. The container will probably hold only 20 objects maximum, so O(n) should be okay.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth actually `_random.Next(1, _weightSum)` was right, because I'm using `rand < kvp.Value + sumExtra`, but then I should probably also change the `1` to `0`. Yeah, now it looks alright

Comment: What if you add the same item (type) twice with different weights?  How does that affect the calculation?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Do you mean the same instance? It would probably error out when adding, because the key is already in the dict. It's not specifically made to select types, but instances at random. You could of cause have another instance of an `AwesomeThing` there with a different weight. As long as the type implements or extends the collections typeparameter (in this example `IThing`) it works. Or you could have a `RandomContainer<string>` to be able to get strings at random with weighs. `randomContainer.Add("cool", 68); randomContainer.Add("awesome", 45);`

Comment: Ok, I understand.  You're trying to select instances and the ones with higher weight will be more likely to be selected.  So if there were two instances of AwesomeThing, one with a high weight and one with a low weight, the one with the higher weight will probably get selected first.